# Computer simulation of a syncroscope

Tags: power-electronics, mains, power-generation

I want to create a computer simulation of a [Synchroscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchroscope). I have searched for descriptions of how a Synchroscope works but none of them unambiguously answer my questions about how to recreate the behavior in a simulation.

Given two waves of similar amplitude/voltage, but differing in frequency and phase, how can I calculate the angle of the needle of a synchroscope? Can the angle of the needle be calculated directly, or should I be looking for how much the needle should deflect clockwise or counterclockwise at a given time-step?

I know that a synchroscope is supposed to show the difference in phase between two waves, and I know frequency must play a part in it as well, but I'm not sure how. A related question about synchroscope behavior I have is: "if the frequencies of the two waves are equal, but they are not in phase, where would the needle point?"

Comment: I don't have time to type up a proper answer, but maybe the formulas in [this Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XRjbewVgacmRXqSNFVFl4YREcF3kuHwj8ZYuGXGf-nM/edit?usp=sharing) will help you. If you make your own copy, and play with changing the values in column B, you'll quickly see what it does. I'll leave the spreadsheet up for a few days, and then I will delete both it and this comment.

Answer (score 1):

If \$V_1=A\sin(\omega_1t+\phi_0)\$ and \$V_2=A\sin(\omega_2t+\psi_0)\$ then calculating angles:

$$\text{phase} = (\omega_1t+\phi_0)-(\omega_2t+\psi_0)$$ which should be changing with time, or

$$\text{phase} = (\omega_1-\omega_2)t +(\phi_0-\psi_0)$$ at the "difference of frequencies" if frequencies do not change.

When frequencies are ~ equal, "phase" can be canceled if necessary by a "phase synchonizer system" at what angle needed which can be changed for "changing" the "circulating powers"  on the mains, for example.

In french, [reference](http://server.idemdito.org/electro/elec/gen/synchro.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The needle angle represents the phase difference between the two supplies.

If the frequencies are different the needle will move (round) at rate equal to the difference in frequencies.